# Retrieving dota 2 steam names when you first connect to a game

Tags: python, web-scraping, server

I am trying to scrape everyone's player names from a match when I first connect to a match.  I then want to pass these names to an application (I'm guessing I'll use python?) that will connect to dotabuff and scrape each players top 5 hero's played and output them.  Is this a reasonable goal?

The examples I have come across seem to demonstrate how to get data after a match is over.  I really just need the player names as soon as I connect to the server.  Is python the best route to go for this? Any suggestions on other languages I could use?

I have good knowledge of C, C++, Java, and assembly language but am completely new to this field.  Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Dota2 specifics and I can't check since no one is currently playing it on my friends list so I'm shooting blanks here, but other Source games allow you to query server information, including player list.

You can read more about it here: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries